# How can I normalize units from CSSStyleDeclaration object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I was working on a project transitioning the left CSS property of an element, which was defined as a percentage (e.g. 100% to 0%). I was developing in Chrome which was giving me `style` values for `left` as a percentage, this ***was*** working the way I wanted, until I tried it in another browser (any other browser actually). I set up this simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bodine30/B59k8/) to demonstrate. Generally, most values are converted to pixels before being reported, but not chrome.
The second part of this question would be; Is there a way to get the other browsers to report the style property as it was originally set? (e.g. px, %, em, in, etc.) without an ugly conversion? and if not is there some other reasonable workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44266) in chrome. Otherwise, All of the other styles and browsers, with the exception of IE, should convert everything to pixels. IE leaves everything in it's own units but also uses a propritary method in browsers older than IE9. [Here's a page I found that talks about that and shows how to convert IE to px.](http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle)

Comment: Nice to know, about the bug. Any ideas for how to normalize units and workaround it? As for IE9, only `lineHeight` appeared in different units. Thanks.

Comment: @bodine I didn't really find much in the way of a workaround. That second link has some information on a workaround for IE though. Having said that my thought is that you would want to check the style for a unit and convert it to pixel based on 100% of a known element. So to convert left:5% to pixel find what 100% width is in pixel and take 5% of that. It's not simple like you asked but the only thing I can think of for the time being.